# How to MySQL array value flatten and copy multi rows

Tags: mysql

I want to flatten "ids" column value from this

| data0 | data1 | data2 | ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | [101,102,103] |
| 2 | c | d | [104,105] |
| 3 | e | f | [106] |

to this table

| data0 | data1 | data2 | ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | 102 |
| 1 | a | b | 103 |
| 2 | c | d | 104 |
| 2 | c | d | 105 |
| 3 | e | f | 106 |

`DB : Mysql 5.7.32`

Thank you all

Comment: Does there exists some upper limit of the amount of separate values per one `ids` value? *from this* - provide this as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts, not as a table.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT data0, data1, data2, JSON_EXTRACT(ids, CONCAT('$[', i, ']')) id
FROM test
-- up to 6 separate values per `ids` value are parsed
JOIN ( SELECT 0 i UNION ALL
       SELECT 1   UNION ALL
       SELECT 2   UNION ALL
       SELECT 3   UNION ALL
       SELECT 4   UNION ALL
       SELECT 5 ) numbers ON JSON_EXTRACT(ids, CONCAT('$[', i, ']')) IS NOT NULL;
```

or

```sql
SELECT data0, data1, data2, JSON_EXTRACT(ids, CONCAT('$[', i, ']')) id
FROM test
JOIN ( SELECT 0 i UNION ALL
       SELECT 1   UNION ALL
       SELECT 2   UNION ALL
       SELECT 3   UNION ALL
       SELECT 4   UNION ALL
       SELECT 5 ) numbers
HAVING id IS NOT NULL;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=519d259e7f53b5365bd515e14c3eb938